# Ul li alignments using float left and right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the ul li depending on the float value.

So if the float is left then it will align left else right. But the issue is that when a li gets float right then it aligns to the right but not at the top.

Html code--

```
<ul>
  <li style="float:left;">Text 1</li>
  <li style="float:left;">Text 2</li>
  <li style="float:right;">Text 3</li>
</ul>
```

Demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/t2qmfkya/

Now they are all in one line but I would like to display it in the following way

```
Text 1    Text 3
Text 2
```

I have no clue if this is at all possible by the html format I have.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not directly conecerning your problem, but still: Float representation is not precise in JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695618/dealing-with-float-precision-in-javascript

Comment: @elementzero23 float precision has absolutely nothing to do with the CSS float property, you're right. So why even mention it here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153789/css-column-count-showing-something-mess/42154054#42154054

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra : Good question. I couldn't think of a CSS only solution. Is jQuery fine ??

Comment: @Pugazh Sorry it needs to be css only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the prettiest, but might help you...

You can target the elements with a particular inline style.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/t72pohL7/1/)

```
ul li[style="float:left;"] {
  clear: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

ul li[style="float:right;"] {
  float: none !important;
}
```

```css
ul {
  width: 180px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li[style="float:left;"] {
  clear: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
ul li[style="float:right;"] {
  float: none !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="float:left;">Text 1</li>
  <li style="float:left;">Text 2</li>
  <li style="float:right;">Text 3</li>
  <li style="float:right;">Text 4</li>
  <li style="float:left;">Text 5</li>
</ul>
```

**Updated**

```
ul li[style="float:right;"] {
  float: none !important;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
```

This ensures that all float:right elements line up.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/t72pohL7/4/)

Comment: I have started liking this solution. Please give me some time to go through and understand.

Comment: To be honest, I think it might be the only way to get what you want, especially if those inline styles are random.

Comment: Good answer, but not perfect. This will fail if i add few more float right items!

Comment: Yes the inline styles are random. That's why this is a complex one.

Comment: @Pugazh I tried adding few more and seems to be alright.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/t72pohL7/3/ and this https://jsfiddle.net/t72pohL7/5/

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra: Are you fine with a jQuery solution ?

Comment: @Pugazh Well spotted.. I'm not sure I can find a solution for this

Comment: @ovokuro I need to think about changing the html structure.

Comment: @ovokuro : Your's is the best answer here, but it might fail in certain scenario's.

Comment: Got a solution. I can remake the html structure in such a way where the li's with float left will list first and then the rest li's with float right will be listed. :). Obviously I will be using css class instead inline styles.

Comment: Answer accepted. Thanks @ovokuro for this brilliant solution.

Answer (score 3):

you can use CSS3 `columns`

```css
ul {
  columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Text 1</li>
  <li>Text 2</li>
  <li>Text 3</li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

More random `li`s

```css
ul {
  columns: 5;
  -moz-columns: 5;
  -webkit-columns: 5;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Text 1</li>
  <li>Text 2</li>
  <li>Text 3</li>
  <li>Text 4</li>
  <li>Text 5</li>
  <li>Text 6</li>
  <li>Text 7</li>
  <li>Text 8</li>
  <li>Text 9</li>
  <li>Text 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "I am trying to align the ul li depending on the float value."

Comment: You should also make the OP aware of the current browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Comment: @Connum really? the vendor prefixes is not enough?

Comment: @dippas not if he/she has to support older versions of IE, which we don't know

Comment: Thank for your solution. The output is exactly the same as I wanted. But as I said each li can have float left or right and they should start from the top of the ul.

Comment: why having float?

Comment: Thats the requirement...Sorry I can't change the html structure.

Comment: LOL you are **NOT** changing html structure, just changing CSS

Comment: Sorry mate in your example you changed the html structure of what I first posted in my ques.

Comment: Wait what?? your HTML structure is a simple `<ul><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul>` thats what I did. **inline styles aren't html structures**

Comment: 'My' html structure was this -- <ul><li style="float:left;">Text 1</li><li style="float:left;">Text 2</li><li style="float:right;">Text 3</li></ul>

Comment: I'm not gonna argue with you, You need to Learn what means **HTML STRUCTURE** and **inline styles**

Comment: Well technically yes you are right  It should be just html(structure + inline styles). In you eg you removed the inline styles.

Comment: inline styles are a bad pratice, so I always remove it, plus I'm using `columns` CSS not `float` CSS, see updated answer btw

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it in this way https://jsfiddle.net/t2qmfkya/5/

```
<ul>
  <li class="right-item" style="float:right;">Text 3</li>
  <li class="right-item" style="float:right;">Text 4</li>
  <li>Text 1</li>
  <li>Text 2</li>  
</ul>


ul {
  width: 180px;
  background: red;
  padding: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul li {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.right-item{
  width: 51%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Rearrange element and use clear both can handle this :

```css
ul {
  width: 180px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="float:left;">Text 1</li>
  <li style="float:right;">Text 3</li>
  <li style="clear:both;">Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why You add <li style="float:right;">Text 3</li> in this function Middle of the li

Comment: @IvinRaj As I said, OP could `rearrange the elements` and use clear both.

Comment: @AndyChen Thanks for your effort.